# Using materialize css without a grid causes input placeholder to be misaligned

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using materializecss without its grid system.
However that makes my input field placeholder text to have left:0.75rem; style.
Is it a bug in materialize or I'm doing something wrong here?
Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4ufn5L3v/ and code below

```
     <div class="card">
     <div class="card-content">
        <form>
           <div class="input-field">
              <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
           </div>
           <div class="input-field">
              <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
              <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
           </div>
        </form>
     </div>
     <div class="card-action">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
           Login
        </button>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed with a small css trick.

The HTML:

```
<div class="input-field placeholded">
    <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate" placeholder="+33642424242">
    <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.placeholded label {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-140%);
    transform: translateY(-140%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My fix was a bit different, but this should also work